# Delete function storing the deleted record as json

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a `function` in my `Postgres` and with this function, I want to delete a record using `table` and `id` and store the record as a JSON.

As you can imagine, I'm getting the table name as a parameter, but at that point, I don't know the name of the fields inside of my table. And I have:

```
create or replace function deletetable(_table text, _id int)
returns json as
$func$
declare
    res json;
begin 
    execute format('SELECT json_to_recordset(::json) FROM ' || _table || ' WHERE id ' || id) into res;
    -- HERE ONCE I GET THE RECORD AS JSON I HAVE TO INSERT IT IN MY TABLE
    return res;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Well, my specific question is, how can I retrieve that information?
With my current function I get:

> SELECT json_to_recordset(::json) FROM table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a log table:

```
create table logtable (
  id serial primary key,
  del_tname text not null,
  del_ts timestamptz not null default now(),
  del_rec jsonb
);
```

Your function should then look like this:

```
create or replace function deletetable(_table text, _id int) 
  returns jsonb as 
$$
declare
  res jsonb;
begin
  execute format('with d as (delete from %I where id = %s returning *) ' 
                 'insert into logtable (del_tname, del_rec) '
                 'select %L, to_jsonb(d) from d returning del_rec', 
             _table, _id, _table) into res;
  return res;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Executing a `select * from deletetable('tablename', 14);` will delete your row, log it to `logtable`, and return the `jsonb` of the row.